# Почему новый проект не видит классы?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно увидеть, Интеллиж почему-то не видит Джавы файл и я не зная в чем проблема. Могу предположить что это произошло после изменения версии Джавы.

Такое уже не впервые и я не зная в чем проблема. Пожалуйста помогите кто знает или сталкивался с таким.

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверь настроен ли SDK (JDK) твоего проекта. Ссылка на то, как это сделать: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#set-up-jdk
2. Проверь настроены ли директории твоего проекта в качестве "Content root". Ссылка на то, как это сделать: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html
3. Сделай ребилд проекта. Ссылка на то, как это сделать: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#rebuild_project

Comment: спасибо, оказывается проблема была в версии Maven. Она была слишком высокой.